# Is there any way I can log the currently executing advice at a Joint Point?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I have a scenario where I have multiple advice being applied on a single joint point because of the common point cut expression. Is there any way through which I can log which advice is currently executing or being executed without giving them different log statements(by means of some method invocations)?

```
/*
     * Advice to check Asset Service 1 response
     */
    @Around(value="@annotation(vs2a) && args(mfa)")
    public MessageFlowAggregator checkAsset1Response(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,ValidateStage2Advice vs2a,MessageFlowAggregator mfa) throws Throwable {
        log.debug(">>> matching advice on {}",joinPoint);
        if(mfa!=null){
            mfa= (MessageFlowAggregator) joinPoint.proceed(); 
            log.debug("<<< returning advice on {}",joinPoint);
        }else{
            log.debug("<<< failing advice on {}",joinPoint);
        }
       return mfa;
    }

    /*
     * Advice to check Customer Service 2 response
     */
    @Around(value="@annotation(vs2a) && args(mfa)")
    public MessageFlowAggregator checkCustomer2Response(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,ValidateStage2Advice vs2a,MessageFlowAggregator mfa) throws Throwable {
        log.debug(">>> matching advice on {}",joinPoint);
        if(mfa!=null){
            mfa= (MessageFlowAggregator) joinPoint.proceed(); 
            log.debug("<<< returning advice on {}",joinPoint);
        }else{
            log.debug("<<< failing advice on {}",joinPoint);
        }
       return mfa;
    }
```

Both the above advice print s same log statement and I am not able to differentiate between them.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just add a prefix to each log message. The alternative would be:

```java
log.debug("Executing advice: " + new Exception().getStackTrace()[0])
```

And of course if you print the same thing twice from within one advice, you should store it in a variable first so as not to make creating exception objects and stacktraces even more expensive. But I think for debugging it should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better that we use logging frameworks logging pattern to get the method name in every log printed. I update the logging pattern to get the desired output in log.

Pattern:

```
logging.pattern.console=%d %-5level %t %logger{2}.%M : %msg%n
```

logs printed as:

```
2018-02-01 19:17:39,798 INFO  main o.s.w.s.s.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2018-02-01 19:17:39,798 INFO  main o.s.w.s.s.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2018-02-01 19:17:39,798 INFO  main o.s.w.s.s.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
2018-02-01 19:17:39,798 INFO  main o.s.w.s.s.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet : Creating SAAJ 1.3 MessageFactory with SOAP 1.1 Protocol
```